# Run viewer command works only from master tex But not from child tex file

Tags: emacs, auctex

i am using Auctex under emacs 24.3.1 on mac.   I am making  master .tex file and many what i call it child .tex files. Run Latex and Run bibtex  commands are working nicely from either  the master file or from child files but i can not view the output except from the master file. 
I would appreciate very much your answer(s). Thanks in advance.
Ayman

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Did you set `TeX-master` appropriately in the child file?  (I would set it as a file-local variable.)

Answer (score 2):

Add the following at the very end of each of your 'child' files:

```
% Local Variables:
% TeX-master: "./my-master-file.tex"
% End:
```

If you already have a `Local Variables` block, just add the appropriate line.

Close and re-open your file; this should set the variable.
(You can also call `M-x normal-mode` if you don't want to close the file.)

Comment: To reload a file there is `M-x revert-buffer` and I would add the suggestion to insert 
`(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)`
 in the `.emacs` file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe i found out what the problem was. It is the configuration of skim and latexmk in the .emacs file. the perfect setting that is really works is as following

```lisp
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Skim's displayline is used for forward search (from .tex to .pdf)
;; option -b highlights the current line
;; option -g opens Skim in the background
;; option -o open Skim in the foreground with full application focus.

'(LaTeX-command "latex -synctex=1")
(require 'tex-site)
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook
    (lambda ()
        (add-to-list 'TeX-output-view-style
            '("^pdf$" "."
              "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline -b %n %o %b")))
)
(server-start)

(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)

(setq TeX-source-correlate-mode t)

(setq TeX-source-correlate-method 'synctex)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-source-correlate-mode)

;; make latexmk available via C-c C-c
;; Note: SyncTeX is setup via ~/.latexmkrc (see below)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (push
    '("latexmk" "latexmk -pdf %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t
      :help "Run latexmk on file")
    TeX-command-list)))
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook '(lambda () (setq TeX-command-default "latexmk")))

;; use Skim as default pdf viewer
;; Skim's displayline is used for forward search (from .tex to .pdf)
;; option -b highlights the current line; option -g opens Skim in the background  
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "PDF Viewer")))
(setq TeX-view-program-list
     '(("PDF Viewer" "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline -b -g %n %o %b")))

(server-start); start emacs in server mode so that skim can talk to it


(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "<S-s-mouse-1>") #'TeX-view))
          )
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

and of course, in the skim you have to do Preferences>Sync>Check for file changes and Preset>Emacs